# Canvas-confetti blowing confetti at the top-left of the screen not in center of the page

Tags: angular, npm, canvas, html5-canvas, fullscreen

I'm using canvas-confetti to show confetti after a positive situation.

```
  public showConfetti(): void {

    confetti.create()({
      particleCount: 100,
      spread: 70,
      origin: {x:1, y: 1 }
    });
  }
```

output:

PF the images

The highlighted section in red is where the confetti is showing, i need to show this in the center of the page.

i tried using z-index but couldn't achieve the expected result.

when i gave canvas size to height,width to 100%, the confetti shapes looks distorted and this is affecting the user experience.

```
canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

[image]
[image]

i need to show confetti in entire screen with no compromise on user experience.

Tried using different packages too but facing same issue on them.

Answer (score 0):

Set origin (x,y) positions using getBoundingClientRect